# match product and copy a row range to Sheet 2

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel

I have 2 Sheets. In Sheet1 I have a list of products (400) in column A. In colums B to M is the space for the names of 10 different owners, but each product could have any number of owners in one of these columms. So 1 product could have 3 of the 10 columns with a name and another product could have 5. This is a reference list to indicate who and how many people own each product. this Sheet does not change.

Sheet2 has a list of a selection of these products (max 65) that changes daily manualy. 
I am trying to get the names of the corresponding owners (the whole row of 10) pasted in the daily sheet according to the products in column M.

So it looks where the product is in Sheet1 and then copies the row of owners (B to M) to Sheet2 (M to Y).

I'm not an expert but trying to get more knowledge of Excel as I think it is great! 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Screen shots always help. Even if you can't add the image, uploading it as a link is useful. This way, we can understand exactly what you want. Showing a 'current' and a 'desired' image is really good too.

Comment: Also, B to M is 12 columns, why do you think it's only 10? And M to Y is 13!!!

Comment: Ah yes, sorry. It is B to M = 12 And it was not M to Y but N to Y. I was to quick with typing... :-S

Answer (score 2):

This should be easy with [vlookup](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/VLOOKUP-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65), but I don't understand your WS structure.

Let's say Sheet1 starts at A1 and Sheet2 has the first product at A1

In B1 of Sheet2 you need

```
=Vlookup($A1,Sheet1!$A$1:$M$400,COLUMN(B1),0)
```

Then drag this down and over (to column M and down to the bottom of selections) in Sheet2 to fill in the matches.

Comment: Whilst the structure of their worksheets is definitely not clear, this should really give the OP all they need to get going. +1

Comment: Since the product list on Sheet2 would be in column A, shouldn't the first parameter be $A1 instead of $B1?